# A function converging to zero at infinity is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0, \infty)$.  If $f(x) ≥ 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0$, prove that there exists a $c$ in $[0, \infty)$ such that $f(x) ≤ f(c)$ for all $x$ in $[0, \infty)$.

I'm thinking this might have to do with the maximum/minimum theorem but I have no idea.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is constant $0$, then $c=0$ is OK.
Otherwise there exists $a\geq 0$ such that $f(a)$ is positive.
Take $\varepsilon=f(a)$. Then for all $x$ bigger than some $b>0$, $f(x)$ is lower than epsilon. In the interval $[0,b]$ we then know by the maximum/minimum theorem that $f$ has a maximum $f(c)$ which is bigger or equal to $f(a)$. This is the maximum in all the interval from zero to infinity.

Comment: Why on earth did you change $c=0$ in the beginning to $K=0$. The aim is not to find the maximum value but to find $c$ in the domain so that $f(c)$ is the maximum. So here $c=0$ will make $f(c)=0\geq f(x)=0$ for $f$ constant.

Comment: Another thing that puzzles me: why do you use capital letters where everyone else uses lower case? The function is $f$ not $F$, constants are more often denoted $k$ that $K$ etc.

Comment: @String for me what is important is to express the concept, the formality I keep to other cases (-:

Comment: I agree with you on that point :)

Comment: @String now I added to your edition "if f is constant $0$ then c=0 is OK

Comment: That's really good!